# undefined en datos de un formulario en javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, undefined

ya he revisado todo el codigo y he rebuscado en toda la web y no encuetro la solucion ya que todo parece estar bien!!sin embargo me sigue dadno error!!

en mi router.js

```
ruta.post('/des',(req,res)=>{
 console.log(req.file);
 res.render('enviado');

});
```

en mi vista

```
<div class="card-body">
         <form action="/des" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
           <div id="estilo-des">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Escriba nombre del plato"/>
            <br></br>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="37" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion del plato"></textarea>
            <br></br>
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="d" value="guardar">
            </div>
          </form>
```

el error que me da es "undefined" y asi mas nada!!!

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que da `undefined`? ¿De dónde sale `file` en tu código?

Comment: No entiendo que quiere hacer... pero en la ruta veo que intenta acceder a un archivo... y no veo ningun `<input type=file>` en el formulario

Comment: quiero subir una foto y en el mismo post subir comentarios y titulos de la foto!

Comment: en el router deberia de ser **req.files**

Answer (score 0):

al final el problea es que no llamé a BodyParser! por eso me da error! aunqeu el errror de undefined me sigue dando cuando subo la foto con el titulo y la descripcion en el mismo post con formidable